# Send POST request via Fetch from frontend and handle request on backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

Thank you for your time.
I am trying to build an application where I need to send a POST request from the client to the server. But I always get this same problem of request body being undefined.

On client side:

```
const addProblem = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = document.getElementById("addForm");
    const problemLink = form.firstElementChild.value;
    const page = document.getElementById("page").innerHTML;
    const data = {
      problemLink: problemLink,
      page: page,
    };
    fetch("/addProblem", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then((res) => {console.log("done")})
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
const addBtn = document.getElementById("addProbBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener('click',addProblem);
```

Server

```
//native node modules
const path = require("path");

//external node modules
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

const MONGODB_URI =  "hello world";

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

// routes
const hubRoutes = require("./routes/hub");

app.use(hubRoutes);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("server started on port 3000");
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Routes

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const hubController = require("../controllers/hub");

router.get("/",hubController.getHub);

router.get("/dsaProblems",hubController.getDsaProblems);

router.post("/addProblem",hubController.addProblem);

module.exports = router;
```

I can see in the networks tab that the request is sent without an issue. The payload is exactly what I want - JSON data. But on ther server when I try to access `req.body`, I get `undefined`.

Please help! Following is the controller where I handle the request.

```
exports.addProblem=(req,res,next)=>{
    
    console.log(req.body); //request body undefined here :(
    const problemLink = req.body.problemLink;
    const page = req.body.page;
    const newProb = new Problem({
        problemLink:problemLink,
        status:false
    });
    newProb.save()
    .then(savedDoc=>{
        res.redirect(`/dsaProblems/?async=true&itemspp=10&page=${page}`)
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: do you have a body parser configured on the server?

Comment: yes I do... please review. I added the server code as well.

Comment: yes, I see that you do now that you added almost all relevant information to the question - where's the `/addProblem` handled? perhaps you need `app.use(hubRoutes);` **after** you add the bodyparsers - assuming that's where `/addProblem` is handled - as I believe currently the addProblem handler will be called before the bodyparser middleware

Comment: Oh yes... you are right!!! I am stupid.... gonna delete this silly question now.
Thankyou very much.

Comment: I didn't KNOW I was right, it was a guess - not a silly question - you learned something